# display imageView

Tags: android

if i have an ImageView and i want to display it if sum = 10 otherwise it must be hidden
how can i do this in java

```
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/a"
            android:src="@drawable/cancel" 
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
              android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/delete"

           ></ImageView>
```

thansk

Comment: Plz show us the code you use to calculate sum

Comment: holder.alert = (ImageView) convertView
    .findViewById(R.id.alert);  so each student in my adapter have an icon which will show only in sum 10 for each student where i can but the code to disply i do not want it do but in onclick so where i should put the code

Answer (score 1):

Put this code

```
if(sum !=10)
{
  imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

to hide ur imageview